# Bash match string with regex

Tags: regex, string, bash

I am using bash 4.1.10(4)-release and I trying to use a regex to match against two capital letters [A-Z]{2} and then anything. So for example `BXCustomerAddress`, `CAmaterial` would be acceptable, but `WarehouseMessage` would not. I have the following script for testing purposes:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "Ce" =~ [A-Z]{2} ]]; then
    echo "match"
fi
```

My questions are:

1. When I run this script, why does it return that I have a match?
2. Does anyone know how I could achieve my desired results?

Comment: Is that the whole input string? Try this: `[A-Z]{2}.*`

Comment: Check `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` if `nocasematch` or `nocaseglob` is enabled there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you have `shopt nocaseglob` turned on. Turn it off using:

```
shopt -u nocaseglob
```

Now `[[ "Ce" =~ [A-Z]{2} ]]` should not match and will return false.

Comment: Already about to answer :) I assumed `nocaseglob` is only for glob patterns.

Comment: It seems both `nocaseglob` and `nocasematch` affect this behavior.

Comment: I just checked both options:
$ shopt nocasematch
$ shopt nocaseglob

both were turned off. 


Then I tried to change the script by inlining both options:

#!/bin/bash

shopt -u nocaseglob
shopt -u nocasematch

if [[ "Ce"=~[A-Z]{2} ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi

But I get the same results.

Comment: @carl_corder Did you include whitespace around the `=~` operator? Your comment indicates you didn't, although it was included in the original question. Without the whitespace, the expression is treated as a single non-empty string that always evaluates to true.

Comment: @carl_corder: Try this: `shopt -u nocaseglob; shopt -u nocasematch; [[ "Ce" =~ [A-Z]{2} ]] && echo "match"`

Comment: @chepner good catch and thanks for the info. Current code is as suggested by @anubhava:

'#!/bin/bash
shopt -u nocaseglob;
shopt -u nocasematch;

if [[ "Ce" =~ [A-Z]{2} ]]; then
 echo "match"
fi`

But is still matching for some reason.

Comment: @carl_corder: For case sensitivity in CYGWIN [read this doc](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html). If you really want case-sensitivity in Cygwin, you can switch it on by setting the registry value

`HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive`
to `0` and reboot the machine.

Comment: Oh snap! So this is a Cygwin related issue, I will look into the doc you linked. Thanks @anubhava !

Comment: Interesting I used regedit to change the value of

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel to 0, rebooted the machine. confirmed that the value is indeed zero. Ran the script again, same problem. I will keep you guys updated if I figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of the shell option `nocasematch`:

```
$ shopt nocasematch
nocasematch     off
```

Answer (score 1):

`shopt nocasematch` is probably set to `on`. Turn it off with

```
shopt -u nocasematch
```

From the [Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> `nocasematch`
>
> If set, Bash matches patterns in a case-insensitive fashion when
>   performing matching while executing case or [[ conditional commands.

Comment: I added both options to the .bashrc and it is still matching. I failed to mention that I am running the shell through cygwin (if it matters).

Answer (score 0):

After trying out many different combinations, this is what gave me the expected behavior:

```
#!/bin/bash
# [A-Z][A-Z] will not work
# [:upper:][:upper:] will not work
# [[A-Z]][[A-Z]] will not work
# [[:upper:]][[:upper:]] does work

echo "test one"
if [[ "CA" =~ ^([[:upper:]][[:upper:]])+ ]]; then
    echo "match"
fi

echo "test two"
if [[ "Ce" =~ ^([[:upper:]][[:upper:]])+ ]]; then
    echo "match"
fi
```

I get the expected results of:

```
test one
match
test two
```

Thanks for everyone's help